# Jumping from one case to the default case in switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

```
switch(ch){
          case 'a':
                 //do something, condition does not match so go to default case
                 //don't break in here, and don't allow fall through to other cases.
          case 'b':
                 //..
          case 'c':
                 //..
          case '_':
                 //...
          default:
                 //
                 break;
}
```

In a switch statement like above one I enter case 'a', I break only if the condition inside it occurs, otherwise I want to jump to default case. Is there any other way of doing this rather than labels or gotos?

Answer (score 29):

`goto` For The Win

```
switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
        if (1) goto LINE96532;
        break;
    case 'b':
        if (1) goto LINE96532;
        break;
LINE96532:
    default:
        //
        break;
}
```

Comment: But what about the rule that says you will be struck by lightning if you write spaghetti code :p ?

Comment: @KirkWoll: It works. I have put a [running example at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/JlyAoj). Does "chrome developer console" accept C code?

Comment: @pmg, lol, terrible terribly sorry.  I googled "javascript switch goto" and this was the second hit.  In my inattentiveness, I hadn't realized this question has nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: How do I do this in javascript? I belive there is no goto in javascript

Answer (score 8):

Just reorder the cases so that that case is the last:

```
switch(ch){
          case 'b':
                 //..
          case 'c':
                 //..
          case '_':
                 //...
          case 'a':
                 //do something, condition does not match so go to default case
                 if (condition)
                     break;
                 //don't break in here, and don't allow fall through to other cases.
          default:
                 //
                 break;
}
```

Comment: but this time case 'b' will be problem.

Comment: Ah, all the cases have to behave equally? Then, you have to explain your question a little bit more, because, for example, the condition depends on the value of the case?

Comment: Yeah, but the condition inside it don't have to depend on cases.

Answer (score 7):

If the condition doesn't depend on cases, why put it inside?

```
if (!condition){
  // do default
}else{
  switch(ch){
    case 'a':
      // do a
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I got that question wrong i guess. I mean I should check the condition when the case occurs. Otherwise you'r right.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check the condition only if ch belongs to ( 'a', 'b', 'c', '-')?

Answer (score 6):

Refactor your code:

```
int test_char(char ch)
{
  switch(ch) {
    case 'a': if (condition) return 0; break;
    case 'b': // ...
    default: return -1;
  }

  return 1;
}

... 
// defaults processing switch
switch(test_char(ch)) {
  case 0: break; // condition met
  case 1: // default processing
  default: // case not handled by test_char
}
```

This also adds the benefit of being flexible to test for multiple classes of default processing. Say you have a group of chars [c, d, e, f] which share some common logic. Simply return 2 from test_char() for these cases (possibly after some conditions has been tested), and add a case 2: handler to the default processing switch statement.

Comment: Hmm... I'd forgot about this question. Wonder why I got no response from @thetux4 on it... (I kind of like it too, surely it wasn't too advanced? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if thes is the best answer, but here it goes:

If you absolutely do not want to use labels, and you want to keep the cases in their current order, then you could continue after case 'a' and then check so see if(ch != 'a') at the beginning of each subsequent case, only executing the statement if the condition is true:

```
switch(ch){
    case 'a':
        // do something
    case 'b':
    if(ch != 'a') {
        //do something
    }
    //repeat for each subsequent case
    default:
        //do something
    break;
}
```

This is probably not the most efficient way to solve your problem, but it should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yeah but instead of doing that using goto looks better i guess?

Comment: I agree. goto really sounds like your **best** option.

Comment: Why not efficient? The optimizing compiler is going to figure out the best way to organize the code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have the switch statements first because the condition you're checking for depends on the case (or the case has to be evaluated first before you can check on the condition), simply set a flag inside your `switch` cases, and if that flag is set, then do a default operation.  For instance:

```
int default_true = 0;
switch (case_value)
{
    case 'a': /* if the condition is true, set the default_true flag */

    case 'b': /* if the condition is true, set the default_true flag */

    //...

    default: default_flag = 1; // set the default_true flag to true
}

if (default_flag)
{
    //place your "default" code here rather than inside the switch statement
    //this prevents code reduplication
}
```

Comment: the conditions inside the cases are not same.

Comment: Yes, but you can test for the condition that you're wanting a "default" case for, and set the flag to trigger a run of the "default" code inside the if-statement ... or are you saying that you need a different "default" handler for each case? ... I've cleaned up the code a little to explain what I was meaning a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
char ucResult = 1;
switch(ch){
      case 'a':
          if(ucResult){
             // do something
             if(error) ucResult = 0;
          }
      case 'b':
          if(ucResult){
             // do something
             if(error) ucResult = 0;
          }
      case 'c':
          if(ucResult){
             // do something
             if(error) ucResult = 0;
          }
      case '_':
          if(ucResult){
             // do something
             if(error) ucResult = 0;
          }
      default:
             //
             break;
}
```

With this structure, you can switch to default case from any previous cases. Handy for breaking outer loops too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my solution answers your question. Simply let the cases follow through all the way (beginning with the matching case) but use a condition to disable subsequent cases from running.

```
typedef enum boolean
{
    FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1
} bool;

void pstuff(char input)
{
    bool _skip = FALSE; 
    switch(input)
    {
        case 'a':
            printf("Case a.");
            _skip = TRUE; 
        case 'b': 
            if(!_skip)
            {
                printf("Case b.");
                _skip = TRUE;
            }
        case 'c':       
            if(!_skip)
            {
                printf("Case c.");
                _skip = TRUE; 
            }
        //...
        default: 
            printf("Done!\n"); //Always gets printed.

    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, the post is really old but to answer everyone:
you can simple write 'goto default;' and you will directly jump to the default case without any problems.

Example:

```
        switch (value)
        {
            case value1:
               // do something;
                break;
            case value2:
               // do something
                break;
           .
           .
           .
           .
            case value20:
               // do something
                **goto default;**
           .
           .
            case valueN:
                // do something
                break;

            default:
                // do something
                break;
        }
```